# Equals free function definition in scala

Tags: scala, function

I have started learning Scala and noticed following two definitions.

```
def a(m:Int){
    println("-" * m)
}                                         //> a: (m: Int)Unit
```

And with `=`

```
def a(m:Int) = {
    println("-" * m)
}                                         //> a: (m: Int)Unit
```

and both can be called using `a(2)`

I have noticed that first function is always treated as Int => Unit 
even when it returns something.

Question: How do these two definitions differ internally?

(This might be silly but I don't know how to google this)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you leave off the equals sign, then the return type is always `Unit`.  If you use the equals sign, then the return type can be something else.

The equals-free version is referred to as "procedure" syntax (a procedure is a function that performs some task, as opposed to an expression that evaluates to some value).  However, use of this syntax is now discouraged, and will be disallowed in the future; see https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7605.